# How do I account for an array that doesn't exist?

Tags: arrays, ruby, recursion

So the code works fine if I'm trying to find the size of the land in the middle, but it fails when calculating the size of the small land in the corner. How do I return `0` if it starts checking for land outside of the given arrays?

```
M = 'land'
o = 'water'

world = [[o,o,o,o,o,o],
         [o,M,M,M,o,o],
         [o,o,M,M,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,o,M]]

def continent_size world, x, y
  if world[x][y] != 'land'
    return 0
  end

  size = 1
  world[x][y] = 'counted land'

  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x  , y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y  )
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y  )
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y+1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x  , y+1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y+1)

  size
end

puts continent_size(world, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Please edit to state in words what `continent_size world, x, y` is intended to return. A small example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some guard clauses at the top of your method like:

```
# make sure we don't attempt to index into an array at less than zero
return 0 if x < 0
return 0 if y < 0

# make sure there is a value in the requested slot
return 0 unless world[x]
return 0 unless world[x][y]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def continent_size(world, row, col)
  rows = ([row-1, 0].max..[row+1, world.size-1].min).to_a
  cols = ([col-1,0].max..[col+1, world.first.size-1].min).to_a
  rows.product(cols).count { |r,c| world[r][c] == M }
end

world.size.times { |r| world.first.size.times { |c|
  puts "[#{r},#{c}] -> #{continent_size(world, r, c)}" } }
[0,0] -> 1
[0,1] -> 2
[0,2] -> 3
[0,3] -> 2
[0,4] -> 1
[0,5] -> 0
[1,0] -> 1
[1,1] -> 3
[1,2] -> 5
[1,3] -> 4
[1,4] -> 2
[1,5] -> 0
[2,0] -> 1
[2,1] -> 3
[2,2] -> 5
[2,3] -> 4
[2,4] -> 3
[2,5] -> 1
[3,0] -> 0
[3,1] -> 1
[3,2] -> 2
[3,3] -> 2
[3,4] -> 2
[3,5] -> 1
```

For

```
row = 0
col = 3
```

the steps are as follows. (Note `world_size #=> 4` and `world.first.size #=> 6`.)

```
rows = ([row-1, 0].max..[row+1, world.size-1].min).to_a
  #=> ([-1,0].max..[1,3].min).to_a
  #=> (0..1).to_a
  #=> [0, 1]
cols = ([col-1,0].max..[col+1,world[0].size-1].min).to_a
  #=> ([2,0].max..[4,5].min).to_a
  #=> (2..4).to_a
  #=> [2,3,4] 
a = rows.product(cols)
  #=> [[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
a.count { |r,c| world[r][c] == M }
  #=> 2
```